# Python requests proxy connection timeout

Tags: python, proxy, timeout, python-requests

I am using this code to check proxy servers:

```
def check_proxy(p):
    try:
        r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', proxies={'https': 'https://%s' % p}, timeout=5)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False
```

it works fine with working proxy. it fails with bad proxy after several minutes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/Desktop/general/test_proxyt.py", line 22, in check_proxy
    r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', proxies={'https': 'https://%s' % p}, timeout=5)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 48, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 557, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 413, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /get (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(110, 'Connection timed out')))
```

Is it possible to set proxy connection timeout exception?

Comment: Did you try the exceptions?

Comment: probably need to write HTTPAdapter, for proxy is handled by urllib3

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try `exceptions` that come with the module.

```
def check_proxy(p):
    try:
            r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', proxies={'https': 'https://%s' % p}, timeout=5)
            if r.status_code == 200:

                return True
            else:
                return False
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:

        # Maybe set up for a retry
        print e

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print e
```

Answer (score 0):

To close the circle here, this was a [bug in requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2336) that has since been fixed.

Comment: The link is dead and I'm having this issue

Comment: Commenting here because I am having a similar problem with httpx, and am doing research on how to fix this problem. Disheartening that the link is dead and that this answer is so old =\